# How to insert array value into xpath syntax searching in Selenium IDE

Tags: arrays, selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I'm a beginner in Selenium so maybe my question will not be easy to understand :)

I'm using Selenium IDE 3.17.0 version. I'm trying to check if device names are present on web page under test. Device names are stored into array:

```
execute script || return ["Tablet Samsung Galaxy Tablet A 10 1 2019 LTE 32GB","APPLE IPAD 10.2 2019 128GB","APPLE IPAD 10.2 2019 32GB","APPLE IPAD PRO 2018 11 64GB 4G"] || ArrayDevices
```

After that, I'm trying to use each value from this array in my xpath searching:

```
for each || ArrayDevices || iterator
verify element present || xpath=//a[@class='name']//span[contains(text(),iterator)]
end
```

The main problem is the result of run of this script is always positive even I have a wrong value (just for negative test) in my ArrayDevice. Everything changes if I replace "iterator" from my xpath syntax with certain wrong name like:

```
verify element present || xpath=//a[@class='name']//span[contains(text(),"Tablet Samsung Galaxy Tablet A 10 1 2019 LTE 32GB")]
```

In this way, Selenium provides me expected result "Element not found".

Could you please explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your feedback!

Comment: I don't know well Selenium IDE but what's the output if you correct your 2nd line of code with : `verify element present || xpath=//a[@class='name']//span[contains(text(),'${iterator}')]` ?

Comment: Hello E.Wiest! Thank you for your feedback! The syntax provided by you is working fine but I've got the main point of my issue:
I use "verify element present" function within loop and I don't know why Selenium console provides only the last result of this run. Hence if I have an array with 100 items, Selenium console will show the result of "verify element present" for the last item only. That was confusing for me and I was thinking I'm using wrongly array item in xpath syntax.
So is possible somehow to see the results of verification for each iteration of array in Selenium console?

Answer (score 0):

I guess the solution is simple. Instead of `iterator` you need to write `${iterator}` inside the xpath of the [verify element present](https://ui.vision/rpa/docs/selenium-ide/assertelementpresent-verifyelementpresent) command - **${...}** is the correct Selenium IDE variable syntax.

Comment: Hello Ralf! Thank you for your feedback! you're almost right - we should write like '${iterator}' in xpath syntax (as well as E. Wiest said in the first comment). The confusing thing is Selenium console shows only the last result of "verify element present" function used in my loop. I didn't notice this firstly and that's why I was thinking I'm writing incorrect xpath expression in my code line.
Now my question is possible to see the results of verification for each iteration of array of my loop in Selenium console?